# Excel Formula Query - IF/OR/AND

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to add in two additional conditions to the following formula:

If I3 = Lost = -1

If I3 = N/A = 0

> =IF(OR(I3="Won",I3="Placed"),(F3*(H3-1))*0.95)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test multiple conditions, you need to [nest IF functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-nested-functions-in-a-formula-9d7c966d-6030-4cd6-a052-478d7d844166):

`=IF(OR(I3="Won",I3="Placed"),(F3*(H3-1))*0.95,IF (I3="lost",-1,0))`

Comment: Can you add an explanation to this? SU is looking for long answers with details about why it answers the question. Just giving a single line answer doesn't benefit the community as a whole.

Comment: @CharlieRB I don't agree with you, please see my question on [meta](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/11696/should-i-write-detailed-answers-to-trivial-questions) where I explain my reason.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be a chain of `if`s:

`=IF(first condition,first value,IF(second condition,second value,IF(third condition,third value,else)))`

You can make that as long as you want.